# modifying hex in binary form

Tags: c#, .net, binary, hex

I would like to be able to convert from a hex byte to an 8 bit binary string or bit array, modify a single bit in the string and convert back into a hex byte.

In theory i would have the input of

```
 "FF"
```

convert it to binary and change one of the bits

```
 "11111111" => "11110111"
```

and convert it back

```
 "F7"
```

I cant get Convert.ToInt32() to work properly and Format("X2") wont work either. 
Any ideas?

```
private void changeDObit(int port, int bitNum, int state)
    {
        try
        {
            byte currentstate;
            instantDoCtrl1.Read(port, out currentstate);
            string data0Hex = currentstate.ToString("X2");
            string data0Binary = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(data0Hex, 16), 2).PadLeft(data0Hex.Length * 4, '0');

            if (!data0Binary[bitNum].Equals(state))
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data0Binary);
                sb[bitNum] = (char)state;
                data0Binary = sb.ToString();
                string strHex = string.Format("{0:X2}", sb);
                byte outdata = Convert.ToByte(strHex);
                instantDoCtrl1.Write(port, outdata);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please show us the code that is not working, and that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Why don't you use bitwise operations `0xff & 0xf7` => `0xf7`

Comment: If you have the value as a *byte* to begin with, why do all the conversion at all? To clear a bit: `b = b & ~8`.

Comment: Wow, you want bit operations, but are using `strings` to do it! If you want to check for even number make sure you use this method http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/An-Odd-Way-to-Find-Even-Numbers.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a much simpler version of your entire method:

```
private void changeDObit(int port, int bitNum, int state)
{
    byte currentstate;
    instantDoCtrl1.Read(port, out currentstate);
    var bitValue = 1 << bitNum;
    currentstate = (currentstate & ~bitValue) | (state * bitValue);
    instantDoCtrl1.Write(port, outdata);
}
```

Assumptions:

- bitNum = 0..7 where 0 is rightmost bit, 1 is next to the left, etc.
- state is either 0 or 1

The way it works is as follows:

When you *and* two numbers together, bitwise, you effectively end up with all the bits that were 1 in both.

So, the first part of the expression:

```
(currentstate & ~bitValue)
```

*ands* together `currentstate` and `~bitValue`.

So, what is `~bitValue`? Well, in this case `bitValue` is 1 bit set, so it has a binary value of either 00000001, 00000010, 00000100, 00001000, 00010000, 00100000, 01000000 or 10000000.

`~` *inverts* that, turning all 1's into 0's and vice versa. In effect, you're anding `currentstate` with 11111110, 11111101, 11111011, 11110111, 11101111, 11011111, 10111111 or 01111111, leaving all other bits as they were, but clearing out a single bit.

Then, the second part of the expression:

```
| (state * bitValue)
```

Here we multiply `state`, which is either 0 or 1, with `bitValue`, that same 7-zeroes-and-1-bit-set value from above, and the result is *ored* into the final result. In effect, if `state` is 1, we set the bit, otherwise we don't.

So, the expression is thus as follows:

- First make sure the interesting bit is cleared
- And then optionally (if `state` is 1), set it